# Why react returns same value in every increment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'v written the code below but always return `0`. Why?

```js
    const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {

        const ti = setInterval(() => {
            setInc(prevState => prevState + 1);
            console.log(inc);
        }, 3000)

        return () => {
            clearInterval(ti);
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: This is because of `closure`. You need to add `inc` as a dependency in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inc` is assigned a value at the top of the component. It doesn't change until the component re-renders.

Your `useEffect` runs the function you pass to it **once** (because the dependency list is `[]`). That function [closes over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the value of `inc` during *the first render*.

Every time `setInterval` triggers the function you pass to it, it sees that closed over value of the original `inc`.

The updated values are only available in:

- The re-rendered component
- The callback function you pass to `setInc`

---

So log it during the re-render of the component instead of inside the interval. You can use a second effect hook to log it only when it changes.

```
const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {

    const ti = setInterval(() => {
        setInc(prevState => prevState + 1);
    }, 3000)

    return () => {
        clearInterval(ti);
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inc);
}, [inc]);
```